# No se muestra el texto en el correo electrónico al usar PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Estoy haciendo un sistema de enviar correos electrónicos al usuario, pero cuando lo envío el formato y las imagenes aparecen correctamente en el correo, sin embargo el texto no. Por favor alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Imagen de cómo se ve el correo electrónico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen del código(Ya que es mucho texto voy a adjuntar una imagen y parte del HTML que uso para mostrar el contenido).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de cómo se debería ver el correo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parte del codigo para enviar el email:

```
<tr>
   <td class="h1 center pb25" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Noto Sans', Arial,sans-serif; font-size:35px; line-height:46px; text-align:center; padding-bottom:70px;"><multiline>Diseño web y Marketing digital</multiline></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Noto Sans', Arial,sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; text-align:center;"><multiline>Registrate en nuestro sitio web y recibe un 10% de descuento al contratar nuestros servicios</multiline></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

lo mas sencillo seria que todo lo que estas mandando al $mail->body le hagas un echo y comentes el envio del mail, al cargar la pagina vas a ver que es lo que se manda y vas a poder ajustarlo sin tener que enviar un mail para testear cada vez e incluso inspeccionarlo desde el navegador.

Intuyo que lo que esta pasando es que la imagen queda sobre el texto, podes probar mediante css usar z-index:100 para el elemento que queres traer al frente.

Por otro lado veo que estas usando tr y td pero no tenes una tabla, tambien puede venir por ahi, podes probar poniendo el texto en tags p asi

```
<p class="h1 center pb25" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Noto Sans', Arial,sans-serif; font-size:35px; line-height:46px; text-align:center; padding-bottom:70px;">Diseño web y Marketing digital</p>
<p class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:'Noto Sans', Arial,sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; text-align:center;">Registrate en nuestro sitio web y recibe un 10% de descuento al contratar nuestros servicios</p>
```